# Help me upgrade my pf.conf for OpenBSD 4.7

Tags: openbsd, pf

I'm planning on upgrading my OpenBSD to 4.7 (from 4.6) and as you may or may not know, they changed the syntax for pf.conf.

This is the relevant portion from the [upgrade guide](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/upgrade47.html):

> #### pf(4) NAT syntax change
>
> As described in more detail in this mailing list post, PF's separate nat/rdr/binat (translation) rules have been replaced with actions on regular match/filter rules. Simple rulesets may be converted like this:
>
> ```
> nat on $ext_if from 10/8 -> ($ext_if)
> rdr on $ext_if to ($ext_if) -> 1.2.3.4
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> match out on $ext_if from 10/8 nat-to ($ext_if)
> match in on $ext_if to ($ext_if) rdr-to 1.2.3.4
> ```
>
> and...
>
> ```
> binat on $ext_if from $web_serv_int to any -> $web_serv_ext
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> match on $ext_if from $web_serv_int to any binat-to $web_serv_ext
> ```
>
> nat-anchor and/or rdr-anchor lines, e.g. for relayd(8), ftp-proxy(8) and tftp-proxy(8), are no longer used and should be removed from pf.conf(5), leaving only the anchor lines. Translation rules relating to these and spamd(8) will need to be adjusted as appropriate.
>
> N.B.: Previously, translation rules had "stop at first match" behaviour, with binat being evaluated first, followed by nat/rdr depending on direction of the packet. Now the filter rules are subject to the usual "last match" behaviour, so care must be taken with rule ordering when converting.
>
> #### pf(4) route-to/reply-to syntax change
>
> The route-to, reply-to, dup-to and fastroute options in pf.conf move to filteropts;
>
> ```
> pass in on $ext_if route-to (em1 192.168.1.1) from 10.1.1.1
> pass in on $ext_if reply-to (em1 192.168.1.1) to 10.1.1.1
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> pass in on $ext_if from 10.1.1.1 route-to (em1 192.168.1.1)
> pass in on $ext_if to 10.1.1.1 reply-to (em1 192.168.1.1)
> ```

Now, this is my current pf.conf:

```
#       $OpenBSD: pf.conf,v 1.38 2009/02/23 01:18:36 deraadt Exp $
#
# See pf.conf(5) for syntax and examples; this sample ruleset uses
# require-order to permit mixing of NAT/RDR and filter rules.
# Remember to set net.inet.ip.forwarding=1 and/or net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
# in /etc/sysctl.conf if packets are to be forwarded between interfaces.

ext_if="pppoe0"
int_if="nfe0"
int_net="192.168.0.0/24"

polemon="192.168.0.10"
poletopw="192.168.0.12"
segatop="192.168.0.20"

table <leechers> persist

set loginterface $ext_if
set skip on lo

match on $ext_if all scrub (no-df max-mss 1440)

altq on $ext_if priq bandwidth 950Kb queue {q_pri, q_hi, q_std, q_low}
queue q_pri priority 15
queue q_hi priority 10
queue q_std priority 7 priq(default)
queue q_low priority 0

nat-anchor "ftp-proxy/*"
rdr-anchor "ftp-proxy/*"

nat on $ext_if from !($ext_if) -> ($ext_if)
rdr pass on $int_if proto tcp to port ftp -> 127.0.0.1 port 8021
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2080 -> $segatop port 80
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2022 -> $segatop port 22

rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 4000 -> $polemon port 4000
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 6600 -> $polemon port 6600

anchor "ftp-proxy/*"

block

pass on $int_if queue(q_hi, q_pri)

pass out on $ext_if queue(q_std, q_pri)
pass out on $ext_if proto icmp queue q_pri
pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} to any port ssh queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} to any port http queue(q_std, q_pri)
#pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} all queue(q_low, q_hi)

pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} from <leechers> queue(q_low, q_std)

pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port ident queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port ssh queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port http queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq queue q_pri
```

If someone has experience with porting the 4.6 pf.conf to 4.7, please help me do the correct changes.

### OK, this is how far I've got:

I commented out `nat-anchor` and `rdr-anchor`, as describted in the guide:

```
#nat-anchor "ftp-proxy/*"
#rdr-anchor "ftp-proxy/*"
```

And this is how I've "converted" the rdr rules:

```
#nat on $ext_if from !($ext_if) -> ($ext_if)
match out on $ext_if from !($ext_if) nat-to ($ext_if)
#rdr pass on $int_if proto tcp to port ftp -> 127.0.0.1 port 8021
match in on $int_if proto tcp to port ftp rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 8021
#rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2080 -> $segatop port 80
match in on $ext_if proto tcp tp port 2080 rdr-to $segatop port 80
#rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2022 -> $segatop port 22
match in on $ext_if proto tcp tp port 2022 rdr-to $segatop port 22

rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 4000 -> $polemon port 4000
match in on $ext_if proto tcp tp port 4000 rdr-to $polemon port 4000
rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp to port 6600 -> $polemon port 6600
match in on $ext_if proto tcp tp port 6600 rdr-to $polemon port 6600
```

Did I miss anything? Is the anchor for ftp-proxy OK as it is now? Do I need to change something in the other `pass in on...` lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems nobody could or was willing to help me... :(

But I managed to get it working myself. Here's the working `pf.conf` (works with OpenBSD 4.8)

```
#       $OpenBSD: pf.conf,v 1.38 2009/02/23 01:18:36 deraadt Exp $
#
# See pf.conf(5) for syntax and examples; this sample ruleset uses
# require-order to permit mixing of NAT/RDR and filter rules.
# Remember to set net.inet.ip.forwarding=1 and/or net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
# in /etc/sysctl.conf if packets are to be forwarded between interfaces.

ext_if="pppoe0"
int_if="nfe0"
int_net="192.168.0.0/24"

polemon="192.168.0.10"
poletopw="192.168.0.12"
segatop="192.168.0.20"

table <leechers> persist

set loginterface $ext_if
set skip on lo

match on $ext_if all scrub (no-df max-mss 1440)

altq on $ext_if priq bandwidth 950Kb queue {q_pri, q_hi, q_std, q_low}
queue q_pri priority 15
queue q_hi priority 10
queue q_std priority 7 priq(default)
queue q_low priority 0

block

match out on $ext_if from !($ext_if) nat-to ($ext_if)
pass in on $int_if proto tcp to port ftp rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 8021
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2080 rdr-to $segatop port 80
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 2022 rdr-to $segatop port 22
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 4000 rdr-to $polemon port 4000
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 6600 rdr-to $polemon port 6600

anchor "ftp-proxy/*"

pass on $int_if queue(q_hi, q_pri)

pass out on $ext_if queue(q_std, q_pri)
pass out on $ext_if proto icmp queue q_pri
pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} to any port ssh queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} to any port http queue(q_std, q_pri)
#pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} all queue(q_low, q_hi)

pass out on $ext_if proto {tcp, udp} from <leechers> queue(q_low, q_std)

pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port ident queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port ssh queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to ($ext_if) port http queue(q_hi, q_pri)
pass in on $ext_if inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq queue q_pri
```

I had it working for over six months now. Since no one was posting an answer and this is basically working now, I decided to post my own solution. Given that this thread has over 1k views, this might help someone...